# Is it possible to make POJOs generated with the Avro Maven plugin play nice with Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, avro

The problem I'm having with Avro is that we are required to use title case names for our data model, but camel case for the rest of our data structures such as DTOs. Here is an example:

```json
{
  "name": "UserRecord",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Username",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CreateUserRequestDTO {
  private UserRecord userRecord;
}
```

The Maven Avro plugin will generate the `Username` field like this:

`private String Username;`

So we have an ugly mix in our code of fields that are title-cased in some cases and camel cased in others. Is there a good way to make Jackson's `ObjectMapper` able to read both of these property name conventions?

The case mixing is resulting in the Avro fields that are title-cased not getting recognized by Spring Boot's ObjectMapper and all of their fields are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if it will actually work in your use case, but maybe you can enable the [Jackson's mapper configuration](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features) property `ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES`:

> If enabled, the bean properties will be matched using their lower-case equivalents, meaning that any case-combination (incoming and matching names are canonicalized by lower-casing) should work.

You can customize the value in your `application` configuration file under the configuration key `spring.jackson.mapper.*`, something like:

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
      mapper:
          ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES: true
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't know if that's the best solution, but it sure looks like a good starting point. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Mike, thanks. Yes, you are right, I think it will work but in the long term it would be preferable to solve the problem generating the correct field names, for example, to avoid any possible performance penalties derived from the need for the transformation performed by Jackson.